# ReCaptchaNoCaptcha support for VisualEditor in MediaWiki?

Tags: javascript, php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-installation

Need help with MediaWiki installation. I successfully installed MediaWiki. Added VisualEditor and Mobilefrontend.

With this in place you can edit my site using visual editor but you cannot save it because of ConfirmEdit ReCaptchaNoCaptcha.  Also in mobile, VisualEditor is not loading at all. ConfirmEdit Simple CAPTCHA is working fine only ReCaptchaNoCaptcha is not working with VisualEditor.

If you look at https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-VisualEditor/blob/master/modules/ve-mw/init/ve.init.mw.ArticleTarget.js#L766

You can see

> "API for different things in the UI. At this point we only support the
>   SimpleCaptcha and FancyCaptcha"

Is there a way to fix this?

```
if ( editApi && editApi.captcha && (
        editApi.captcha.url ||
        editApi.captcha.type === 'simple' ||
        editApi.captcha.type === 'math' ||
        editApi.captcha.type === 'question'
    ) ) {
        this.saveErrorCaptcha( editApi );
        return;
    }
```

How can we add support for ReCaptchaNoCaptcha? 
Here you can see the installation with VisualEditor and ReCaptchaNoCaptcha http://ayurveda.wiki

Comment: For the record, the relevant bug report is [T203478](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T203478).